# Не могу сделать задачу "Ёлочка"

Tags: python

уважаемые!

Подскажите пожалуйста, задача следующая:

На вход подается некоторая строка. Выведите ее с отступами (количество пробелов, равное позиции строки, начиная с 0).

Формат ввода
Привет

Формат вывода
Привет
Привет
Привет
Привет
Привет
Привет

Моё решение не проходит:

```
a = input()
print(a)
print(" " + a)
print("  " + a)
print("   " + a)
print("    " + a)
print("     " + a)
```

Понимаю что для кого-то задачка покажется смешной, но я только начал осваивать Python, может направите на путь истинный?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так что ли?

```
text = "Привет"

for i in range(len(text)):
    print(f"{' ' * i}{text}")
```

кол-во пробелов в питоне вы можете задать как `символ * кол_во символов`

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что код работает только если длина слова равна 6 символам, от Вас требуется, чтобы программа работала при любой длине слова. Это можно реализовать, используя так называемый цикл с параметром. Наиболее простое решение для новичка выглядит так:

```
text = input()  # ввод данных
for i in range(len(text) + 1):  # условие цикла
   print(' ' * i + a)  # тело цикла
```

Ввод:

```
Привет
```

Вывод:

```
Привет
 Привет
  Привет
   Привет
    Привет
     Привет
      Привет
```

Comment: И старайтесь задавать меньше вопросов, где нужно "изобретать велосипед", иначе можно потерять репутацию.